# Churn predictive modelling

Tags: time-series, churn, timelines

I'd like to build a predictive model for predicting churn for a website.

Here is the information I have for each customer :

What they did :

- visit the website
- Buy something
- Do not read thenewsletter
- Read thenewsletter

and when :

- the date of the action

For instance for a customer X :

- 90 days ago : visit the website
- 50 days ago : do not read the
  newsetter
- 20 days ago : do not read the newsletter

The goal is to predict if a customer is gonna be inactive based on this rule :
If the customer did not visit, buy or read our email on the last 12 months, he's lost.

For now, I'm gonna use this data structure (example with the customer X) :

```
User_id | Last_action_1 | Last_action_2 |Last_action_3 |
  X       Do not read       Do not read       Visit
```

The problem is that I lost the time information, I just retain the order.

What is it recommanded to keep it ?

I think about these ideas, but **I think there is better practices** :

```
User_id | Last_action_1 |Last_action_1_date |  Last_action_2 |Last_action_2_date| Last_action_3 |Last_action_3date   
  X       Do not read      20 days ago           Do not read       50 days ago      Visit         90 days ago
```

Comment: Last_action_1 seems to be the same as Last_action_2. This should be buy something I think.

Comment: No this user didn't be anything, take a look on his historical.